# Android app works on simulator but it crashes on device

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, crash

My simple app in mainactivity when the button "start" is clicked, it invokes a methode of a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and this method invokes onReceive(Context context, Intent intent). The code of the method onReceive does a call phone to a number that i passed as extra with the intent that invoke onReceive, in this way:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wl.acquire();
    Bundle dati = intent.getExtras();
    String number = dati.getString("number");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    context.startActivity(callIntent);

    wl.release();
}
```

Now, the app works on the android studio simulator, but when i run it on my device, when i click on the button "start", the app crashes and i don't know why.
i have done any permission in the manifest file.

Comment: Can you tell what Android version you are running in simulator and your actual device?

Comment: What error are you getting in adb?

Comment: Also put some code breakpoints in your onReceive method. Wrap in try and catch, is it erroring in the startActivity() function?

Comment: in simulator there is android 7.1, in my device,xiaomi mi5, android 6. error from in adb? i have not log error file.
i don t know if there is an error in the startActivity function because in simulator it works

Comment: You should look in the logcat of the device. You will see the error and stacktrace. Post that in your question.

Comment: I fixed it. i had to insert this method to the intent before startActivity(callIntent)
    callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);